# How to fix the issue if app is crashed in android?

Tags: android, debugging, exception

I have developed and put an android application in Google Play store.

Someone inform me that the app is crashing while doing something in application.

As a application developer,

1. How to find the problem and fix it in android?
2. Is there any tool or framework to debug the crashed app in android?

Comment: 1) Please format your question better. It is a pain to read, and will affect the amount of time that people take to answer you

Comment: 2) Yes, there are LOTS of options. The Google Play Store itself gives you Crash Reports under the Developer Console... including the Stacktrace of what happened. That should be your first step.

Comment: 3) If that is not enough, search SO for more information. There are LOTS of questions in this manner, and its good to not duplicate. I answered one here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27415684/1226095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many sdks out there which can be incorporated in your app.

You can use 
1. [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/)
2. [localytics](http://www.localytics.com/)
3. [crittercism](https://app.crittercism.com)

Its always a best practice to include some analytics tools in your android application to know where users are spending a lot of their time. I personally like [flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/).

Since you have already uploaded the apk you should check it out in the google play developer console. Even google will provide the crash data, and it is the only resource you have.

As far as fixing the application goes you can do it only by uploading a new apk and asking the users to update the app.

Answer (score 2):

ACRA is a right choice for you to analyze the crash report. Please refer the following link to implement in your project.

https://github.com/ACRA/acra

And also, You can find the crash report in your developer console if the the user has sent the crash report while force closing of the application.

Please ensure that you have not enabled the proguard. if you have enabled proguard, try decode the lines using the following link

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding